# Outlook Interop from c# service

Tags: c#, email, service, interop, outlook

I have a barebones c# service installed and want to use the outlook.interop functionallity from within my program. Just to detect and read new emails recieved. I have the program that does this but it is a form application. Is it possible to use outlook.interop from a C# service?

Comment: If you need further assistance please add some information about your specific environment (mail server) and the task you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Better avoid using an interactive application within a service environment. Using Outlook from a service is not supported by Microsoft and will get you probably in all sorts of trouble (think message boxes popping up for instance).

If you want to talk to an Exchange server better use CDO/MAPI or the Exchange Web service API.

If you want to talk to a POP3 or IMAP server use a dedicated library.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at the [Redemption RDO Library](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdo_introduction.htm) (commercial third-party tool), which is effectively a managed wrapper for MAPI that allows out-of-process access to Outlook stores. To detect new mail, you could subscribe to the [`RDOStore.OnNewMail`](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/rdostore.htm#events) event.